# How to add a link to a jumbtron background image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have jumbroton that has a background image. I'm trying to add a link that directs to another page. Basically, when you click the image it redirects to another page.

I've tried adding an image tag and then adding a src to it, however it adds another image on top of the image I already have in the background.

```
.jumbotron-fall{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("/Users/admin/Documents/Nas/EAN x Twin Cousin tm.jpg");
    background-size: 700px 400px;
    background-position: center;
}

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-fall text-center row no-gutters">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="fall2018.html">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can always get rid of the background and use the img tag. You don't have to have a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap the jumbotron div in a link.

```
.jumbotron-fall{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("/Users/admin/Documents/Nas/EAN x Twin Cousin tm.jpg");
    background-size: 700px 400px;
    background-position: center;
}

<a href="fall2018.html">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-fall text-center row no-gutters">
        <div class="container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap the container into the `<a>`-Tag or you could position the `<a>`- `absolute` like this:

```
.jumbotron-fall{
  ...
  background-size: 700px 400px;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative; // <-- IMPORTANT LINE
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```